# How to obtain Polkadot release version?

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node

How can I obtain the Polkadot release version in Rust that my node was compiled against?  I want to log it at node startup.  e.g.  `Polkadot-0.9.42`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a substrate-specific question but rather a rust/dependency question. You're asking, if I am not mistaken, a way to pull in the string from `branch=` in the following:

```
polkadot-parachain = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot", default-features = false, branch = "release-v0.9.42" }
```

Firstly, why not embed the polkadot version directly into your node like so?

```rs
log::info!("this node was compiled against polkadot-v0.9.42");
```

This has the advantage of being a simple solution, and since you're updating your polkadot/substrate dependencies anyways, might as well update this loc as a part of the process.

AFAIK, this is not possible to do *inside* a rust program, but you can use `cargo metadata` to check what dependencies your program is using, and then maybe use some fancy regex to pull in the specific string, such as match something along the lines of `cargo metadata | rg 'release-v0.*'`

Now with that said you can certainly run this command inside rust using `Command` :

```rs
use std::process::Command;

    let output = Command::new("cargo")
        .arg("metadata")
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute command");

    if output.status.success() {
        let stdout = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);
        // -- do pattern matching here --
        println!("Command executed successfully:\n{}", stdout);
    } else {
        let stderr = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr);
        println!("Command failed:\n{}", stderr);
    }
```

But again, this rabbit hole goes deep into writing a rust program just for something very simple to just open up and look.